# Performance issue with timestamp in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, timestamp

I am facing serious performance issues after fixing a query:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    IF (Order_SG.Payment_Date = '0000-00-00', Order_SG.Creation_Date, Order_SG.Payment_Date) AS `DATE`,
    ...
FROM Order_SG
    INNER JOIN Customer USING (Customer__)
    INNER JOIN Order_SG_Detail USING (Order_SG__)
    INNER JOIN Product_Ref USING (Product_Ref__)
    INNER JOIN Reduction USING (Reduction__)
WHERE ...
    -- AND DATE BETWEEN '2016-02-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-11 00:00:00'
    AND Order_SG.Stamp BETWEEN '2016-02-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-11 00:00:00'
    LIMIT 2000
    OFFSET 0;
```

**Before**
The test was performed on `DATE`, and the query would run in 0.174 sec.

[image]

**After**
The test is performed on `Stamp` in 15.564 sec (REM: it makes sense that the query would return more rows).

`Order_SG` contains about 31 million rows.

`Order_SG.Stamp` is defined as following:

[image]

What are my options? How can I solve this performance issue?

**UPDATE**

I have fixed the `2016-02 23:59:59` typo and re-checked my numbers. I have updated my data above.

`SHOW INDEX FROM Order_SG` does not return entries for `Stamp`, but there is a `BTREE` index for `Creation_Date` and `Payment_Date` which are used to create `DATE`.

Comment: Is `AND '2016-02 23:59:59'` just a typo?

Comment: php `max_execution_time` does not affect database query execution times, as php only accounts for CPU time used by php script itself. all the rest (db times, network transfer times) are not included in that. So this is irrelevant.

Comment: @poncha, Alright, just can't find out what that value `'2016-02 23:59:59'` means...

Comment: Maybe there is an index on `date` and not on `stamp`?

Comment: Urm `'2016-02'` as a date is either a typo or wrongly coded

Comment: Oh. right You are ;) This might have affected the performance too. I guess mysql will silently "fix" the datetime but it may be not what was intended.

Comment: @Thorsten There is no index on `stamp`, but there is for `date`. See updates in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no index on `stamp`. So the DBMS has to read record for record from the table in order to check whether it's appropriate or not. With an index on `stamp` it could simply pick the appropriate records via the index.

So create the index, e.g.

```
create index idx_order_sg_stamp on order_sg(stamp);
```

and your query should run fast.

Comment: Need to see the indexes in the other tables, too.